# How to solve this probability problem using Binomial coefficient?

Tags: probability

I am looking for a closed form solution with the help of manipulation of Binomial coefficients.

Here is the problem :
We are given three integers $a,b,c$ .

Constraints : $b>0 , b,a <998244353$

$c<=10^x$
, where $x=18$

Consider an array of size $c$ .

It only consists of only zeroes and ones .

Calculate the probability that the array contains an odd number of $1$'s .

Probability of any array element to be zero , is given by $a/b$ .

Example :
$
c=2
$

$
a=1
$
$b=3$

$(p1=a/b)$

Only the following arrays satisfy the condition ,

1. {0,1} , (probability1) : (1/3)*(2/3) = (2/9)
2. {1,0) , (probability2) : (2/3)*(1/3) = (2/9)

Final answer : 2/9 + 2/9 = 4/9

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120941/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-bezos-how-to-solve-this-probability-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p(c)$ is the probability of being odd then $p(0)=0$ and $p(1)=\frac {b-a}b$ and $p(c)=\frac{a}{b}p(c-1) + \frac{b-a}{b}(1-p(c-1))$

But as lulu commented, if $0 < a < b$ and there is a limit then it will be $\frac12$ so it might be easier to work with $q(c)=p(c)-\frac12$ so you start with $q(0)=-\frac12$ and $q(1)=\frac{b-2a}{2b}$ and have $q(c)= \frac {2a-b}{b} q(c-1)$ and so as closed forms $q(c)= -\frac12 \left(2\frac{a}{b}-1\right)^c $  and thus  $$p(c)=\frac12 -\frac12 \left(2\frac{a}{b}-1\right)^c$$ and so long as $0 < a < b$ you get $q(c) \to 0$ and $p(c) \to \frac12$ as $c$ increases.